# Howto best pack 2 texture coordinates for fast vertex buffer processing ? (WebGL GPU Float Packing)

Tags: floating-point, glsl, webgl, shader, bit-manipulation

I was wondering what way would be the smartes to pack 2 texture coords for fast usage in vertex shaders given the following circumstances:

- Both texture coords can only be either 1.0f or 0.0f => 1 Bit each would be enough
- I will have to pack those 2 coords into a GLByte (8 bit) attribute variable; however it would be best if 6 bits remain available for other usages

My issues are that I'm not that familiar with the bit-layout of floats to do it myself, but I can imagine that only 1 bit in a 0.0f needs to get flipped to become a 1.0f - i just dunno which one; using only bitwise ops this should be incredible fast (btw: are gpu's also faster about bitwise stuff compared to arithmetic, like CPUs ?).

Comment: Well, the fastest operations are those that you dont need to do.
As you've tagged your question with WebGL I need to tell you that its GLSL ES does not support bitwise operators.

Comment: Seriously ? Its impossible to pack both texture coordinates in just 1 Byte ? That would increase the needed bandwidth tremendously if I need 32x2 instead of 1x8 bits per Vertex..

Comment: You could pack them, but you would need to unpack them via multiplication and division inside your shader. I doubt that this will be faster than having a bigger buffer.

Comment: Well, the main motivation to reduce buffer size is that it contains some static data (all geometry) and some highly dynamic content being updated every 200ms or such. I was also considering using multiple arrays, then I could leave geometry positions and texture coordinates fully static and only change the "texture indices" of those squares.

Comment: In this case, i would argue that keeping the buffers separated will save you lots of bandwidth updating them. Another possible solution would be to do all calculations on the gpu and just calculate your texcoords on the fly, or if thats not possible render them into a texture(f.e. RGBA_4_4_4_4) and do a texture lookup in the vertex shader. Texture lookups in vertex shaders can be quite slow but depending on your buffer size it may increases performance in your case.

Answer (score 0):

It's done like this, in vertex shader:

```
uv = fract(vertex.xy);
normal = fract(vertex.z);
gl_Position = mvp * vec4(floor(vertex), 1.0)
```

Obviously, vertex xyz must be scaled up before storing into VBO by maximum texture resolution, say 256x256 in this case:

```
vbo.push_back(vertex.mul_xyz_scalar(256.0).floor().add_xyz(uv.x, uv.y, normal));
```

So, if vertex.x is .00390625, it becomes 1. Positions below 1/256 are subnormals (lost, floor above truncates it). uv is already assumed to be in 0-1 range. If you really insist, you can just multiply by 2 instead of 256, and anything but 0 and 1 will be lost.

A word of warning. This technique does work *only* if you're bound by memory bandwidth (many vertices, simple shaders, typically very complex static meshes). Otherwise the additional floor() cost in shader is not worth it and you're better off storing uv and normals by side.

Finally, all vertices must be scaled up by 256 like this (if you're using different shaders without packed uv/n), or scaled back down by 256 via mvp matrix (this usually does not incur additional overhead, unless naively done directly in the shader without using existing matrix).

Ninja edit: here is a fast general function for "bytes" packed inside floats.

```
/*
 * Packed with: (x*32768+y*128+z)/32768.0 where x and y are 0-255, z is 0-127.
 * This function returns x and y in 0-256, and z in 0-1 range, scale to 128 as needed.
 */
void unpack887(in float v, out float x, out float y, out float z)
{
  x = floor(v);
  float rem = (v - x) * 256.0;
  y = floor(rem);
  z = rem - y;
}
```